# Connection Sharing over Ethernet Problem

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, sharing

I got my server recently, a pretty beefy server for Virtual Machines currently setup on Proxmox. But my server being away from my router, (router which is positionned somewhere i cannot put the server), it was still close enough to my desktop, so i plugged my server to my desktop using an ethernet cable hoping to share my desktop's wifi. I went on connection settings and set iPV4 to "Shared to other computers", like all wifi to ethernet sharing guides suggest. I have then set a static ip on my server which lets me access Promox on 10.42.0.3 in this case, but somehow, my server still does not receive any internet and i cannot ping anything but my desktop's ip.
What could I do?

EDIT: Client and Server is on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Does your question has anything related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, because the client is on Ubuntu and so is the server...

Answer (score -1):

Okay, it happens ubuntu had set network interfaces on manual, making them dhcp seemed to solve the issue.